# Laravel - override default facade bindings - how?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades

Facades are listed on the linked page at the bottom. My question is... How do I override these service container bindings?

Example, the `Request` facade binds `Illuminate\Http\Request` with the key `request`. I want to create my own class which inherits from `Illuminate\Http\Request` and bind it with the `request` key, instead of the current class. And I can't find which service provider binds this.

Answer (score 3):

So, I kind of did it. First I noticed these bindings were hardcoded in `Illuminate\Foundation\Application::registerCoreContainerAliases()` so I extended this class and overrode this method to change it. I also had to call this class now in `bootstrap\app.php`, but doing all this didn't help, I was still getting an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

So then I discovered that `Illuminate\Http\Request` was directly referenced in `public\index.php` so I tried changing it there to `My\Very\Own\Http\Request` and this worked, finally my implementation was being used.

Finally, I deleted my version of `Application::registedCoreContainerAliases()` and reverted `bootstrap\app.php` because everything is also working without this change.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following answer would be very useful for you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39648307/3912276

I quoted the most important part of the answer. It explains how you can replace/extend the `Mailer` facade

> Write your own implementation of `Mailer`, extending `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer`, in which you can override the send method, implement your checks and call `parent::send()`.
>   Write your own service provider (Extending `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider`), in particular re-implement the register method. It should create an instance of your own Mailer in place of Laravel's own. (You can copy most of the code from Laravel's register method).
>   Now, in your `config/app.php` file, in the providers array, replace `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class`, with your own provider.