# How to create global rules for when to send an email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Currently in our system I send emails by using the laravel mailables like so

`Mail::to($user)->send(new AccountCreation($user))`

This works as intended however in our system we have some complex global rules for when to send an email to a person that should be used everywhere, for example:

```
if ($user->isActive) {
    Mail::to($user)->send(new AccountCreation($user));
}
```

I do not want to check the user every time and would rather the mailable logic handle this.

Is there a clean way to handle global rules for when to send an email?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647329/how-can-i-override-laravel-facade-methods

Answer (score 0):

Make a mail() function in the User model and insert your global rules for all users. So instead of calling:

```
Mail::to($user)->send(new AccountCreation($user))
```

You'll be calling:

```
$user->mail(new AccountCreation($user))
```

You can make your mail function as follows:

```
class User extends Model {
    (...)
    public function mail(Mailer $mailer) {
        if ($this->isActive) {
            Mail::to($this)->send($mailer);
        }
    }
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Hi Andre. Thanks for your answer however looking at the link I commented it seems overwriting the the `MailServiceProvider` is a more elegant way to handle this problem.

Comment: Hi @hdifen I don't agree with you. As a rule that only addresses the `User` model, it should be inside it.